# Optimizing Search: no results returned for phrase search

Tags: php, mysql

I am having a hard time optimizing the search functionality of a project I am currently working on.

Assume the search words for the query below are `Green Apple`.

There are some results for `green` and some results for `apple` but not for the phrase `green apple` therefore, this phrase returns an empty result set.

I was wondering if there is a simple way to basically get all the results for `green` and all the results for `apple` and combine them into one result set, without duplicate code.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM files WHERE keywords LIKE '%".$searchText."%' ORDER BY website, description ASC";
$results = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query);
```

keyword field example

`apple peach pear tomatoe`

I appreciate any suggestions!

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: [Full-text search](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/fulltext-search.html).

Comment: Have you considered using fulltext indexes? Then you'd be able to use fulltext searches.

Comment: You want to learn about the full text search capabilities of MySQL.  Also, you should give an example of what the data looks like.  Why would `keywords` have an entry like "green apples" instead of two rows, one with `'green'` and another with `'apples'`.

Comment: To follow eggyal's comment - full text search using `MATCH(`keywords`) AGAINST('green apple' IN BOOLEAN MODE)` will be of much use in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To follow up on my comment, your query would look like this:

```
SELECT * FROM files WHERE 
MATCH(`keywords`) AGAINST('".$searchText."' IN BOOLEAN MODE) 
ORDER BY website, description ASC
```

Keep in mind that [MATCH AGAINST](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/fulltext-search.html) requires full text index on the columns being searched. In this case, you would go into the structure of your `files` table and put a full text index on the `keywords` column. In phpmyadmin it's a one click button that's in the same area as edit, drop, unique, primary, etc

Comment: +1, Thanks for the reply! This works quite well! :D One minor problem however, if a user searches for `apples` and `apple` is a keyword, the query will return an empty set, any idea how to get around this?

Comment: You can try experimenting with the assortment of options match against offers. Boolean mode is typical but not necessary. I tend to only use match against in boolean mode so I don't think i am the best authority on the other options

Answer (score 0):

What about this kind of thing :

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM files WHERE ('".$searchText."' LIKE concat('%',keywords,'%')) OR (keywords LIKE '%".$searchText."%') ORDER BY website, description ASC";
```

Comment: This will do the trick for a user searching for apples and apple is a keyword